# PHP json_decode returns array and NOT an object

Tags: php, json

I have to do a website with PHP and actually I'm trying with it. For now I want to obtain a JSON from a URL (I've got a web service with Node.js) and show in the screen. The URL returns a JSON object like this:

```
[{"name":"Juan","text":"Oh my god"},{"name":"Pedro","text":"I'm here"}]
```

I have this code in PHP file:

```
<?php 
    $data = file_get_contents('http://localhost:3000/node/busca'); // Returns the JSON
    $terminos = json_decode($data);

    print_r($terminos);

    echo $terminos->name;

?>
```

But `print_r` returns:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [name] => Juan 
            [text] => Oh my god
         ) 
     [1] =>  stdClass Object ( 
            [name] => Pedro
            [text] => I'm here
         )
 )
```

The echo says

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:...\index.php on line 17

What can I do? `json_decode` should return an object and not an array.

Comment: That's because it is an `[…]` array at the outset. [→ see](http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=&assoc=&json=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Juan%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Oh+my+god%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Pedro%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22I%27m+here%22%7D%5D)

Comment: And how I can delete it?

Comment: Delete *what*? Are you trying to handle both cases, or something? Did you expect a different data structure? Only want to use one of the entries? Which? Anything else you want to concretize? (For your question here: you can't delete it, once someone answered it.)

Comment: If you want your script to return one object, fix the script and don't have it return an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON and the decoded PHP is an array of objects.  Try:

```
echo $terminos[0]->name;
```

You have multiple array elements so:

```
foreach($terminos as $object) {
    echo $object->name;
}
```

Comment: Or he can loop it once to get out from the array and directly access the object via `$k->name;` (assuming `$k` assigned from foreach) since its `stdClass` i think?

Comment: This works (with name, sorry) but then, Can't I use print_r? I say, How can I show all the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an encoded array of objects. So you will get an array of objects. Everything is right here.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to OP's question to re-format the array output to:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [name] => Juan 
            [text] => Oh my god
         ) 
     [1] =>  stdClass Object ( 
            [name] => Pedro
            [text] => I'm here
         )
 )
```

Looking at it like this it is quite clear how the individual objects are wrapped and addressable:

```
foreach ($terminos as $idx => $obj ) {
    echo "Name $idx: " $obj->name . PHP_EOL;
    /// ... etc
}
```

Should output:

```
Name 0: Juan 
Name 1: Pedro
```

Answer (score 0):

See [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )


$terminosFalse = json_decode($data, true);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["attribute"]=>
    string(1) "attr1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["attribute"]=>
    string(1) "ATTR2"
  }
}


$terminosTrue = json_decode($data, false);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["attribute"]=>
        string(1) "attr1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["attribute"]=>
    string(1) "ATTR2"
  }
}
```

Comment: That's kind of the opposite of what the OP wants.